# I need a OpenGL demo which use GLKit framework on mac,the demo use GLKBaseEffect for rendering

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, opengl-3, glkit

I'm trying to make a simple app with `GLKit` for `OSX 10.8`, but can't find any examples. Apple documentation is just copied from `iOS` to `Mac` with no real examples. I have a context with `3.2 profile` set up, and a `CVDisplayLink` for drawing but nothing. I'm trying to port some simple drawing from `iOS` (also made with `GlKit`). Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you guys really shouldn't close this question